# how to bind a comma separate string to listbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how would i bind a comma separated string such as: monday,tuesday to a list box control as these items being selected when the list box is already populated as such?
sunday
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
saturday

I started with the following code:

```
string days = null;
List<string> lstdays = new List<string>();

//I get the values from a table such as:

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
//other items
days = dr(7).ToString();
}


if (days.Contains(",")) {
//days =  Tuesday,Thursday

}
else
{
  //days = Monday
 lstbxDays.SelectedValue = days;  //means there is a single day
}
```

Comment: I find your question quite suspicios. What are you trying to achieve (the greater goal)?

Comment: want to bind a comma separate list to a listbox and show those items as being selected

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method for strings:

```
string[] newDays=days.Split(',');

foreach (string d in newDays)
{
 lstDays.Add(d);  //add single day to days List
}
```

If you have also defined a `listBox` , say `listbox1`, you can say:

```
listbox1.DataSource=lstDays;
```

if you have bind the days to your listbox then on the event that the user selects a day ( I don't know how you set it in your program, through button , grid etc) you can set:

```
listbox1.SelectedValue = day; //where day is the var user selects
```

Comment: i tried the following but it only selects the last item in the list:

Comment: if (days.Contains(",")) {
 //bind this string to list box -- Tuesday,Thursday
 string[] newDays = days.Split(',');

 foreach (string d in newDays) {
  lstbxDays.SelectedValue = d; //just gets the last day in the list and selects it
 }
    } else {
 lstbxDays.SelectedValue = days;
    }

Comment: if days contains all of your days separated with commas the above code (dont include anything else) will add all the days in the list as well as in you listbox

Comment: yes, will add but I already have them bound to the list box. i am querying a table to find the ones the user selected/inserted earlier. so from that data row i need to highlight the ones the user has. this: foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
//other items
days = dr(7).ToString();
} grabs the user's selected days from the table, so the string days contains the comma separated list. now i have the lstbxDays prepopulated with all the days from another method. now based on the values from the string days, i need to select the given day in the lstbxDays.

Comment: Let me get fisrt straight this..you want your listbox to contain in each selection only one or multiple days?

Comment: Yes, i have it so it works by selecting one day; trying to figure out how it would work if there are multiple days to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the data from a `DataTable`, then something like

```
void BindDayList( ListBox lb , DataTable dt , string textColumnName , string valueColumnName )
{
  lb.DataSource     = dt              ;
  lb.DataTextField  = textColumnName  ;
  lb.DataValueField = valueColumnName ;
  lb.DataBind()     ;
  return ;
}
```

If you've got a flat string then something like the following would probably work:

```
void BindDayList( ListBox lb , string listOfDays )
{
  int i = 0 ;
  lb.DataSource = days
                  .Split(',')
                  .Select( x => new ListItem( (++i).ToString() , x.Trim() ) )
                  ;
  lb.DataBind() ;
  return ;
}
```

Comment: is ListBoxItem only available in winforms or am i missing something?

Comment: @user3642720: Sorry, [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx), not `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: i tried the 2nd example and it replaced everything in the list box with numeric values. so instead of selecting it did: 1 and 2

Comment: The first value in the constructor is the *value* of the list item (the key); the second is its text (display) value. Feel free to read the documentation and adjust it to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
lstbxDays.DataSource = days.Split(',');
```

considering **days** is your comma separated string
Hope this helps!

Comment: that would be if i wanted to populate a list box, right? i think i need to loop through the items in the list and have them as selected.

Comment: Yes, when you want to bind the list with comma separated values. You also want select all items in list?

Comment: yes, in the listbox show the items the user has as selected

Comment: ok, do this lstbxDays.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended; and after binding data do this for (int i = 0; i < lstbxDays.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lstbxDays.SetSelected(i, true);
}
 to select all items.

Comment: setselected is unknown

Comment: in which you are trying this  win forms or wpf?

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone as the examples helped - got it working with this code to select multiple days:

```
//days = tuesday,thursday

string[] s = days.Split(new char[] { ',' });

foreach (string lst in s)
{
 lstbxDays.Items.FindByText(lst.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```